# Java Buffered Stream Writer writes short and corrupts DOCX files

Tags: java

I am writing a file upload Java app, and my issue is that my buffered writer is writing files short of their complete file size. When I record the bytes written, new file size vs old file size - there is always a difference - my buffered reader stops short based on the buffer size.

So when my buffer is set to 1024 for example - it only writes increments of 1024, but not the remaining bytes (the last few bytes that are less than 1024 bytes). DOCX (all X Office Files) are picky about their file size and when you write them short, they get flagged in office as corrupted.

```
       int originalSize = (int) file.length();

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bout = null;
        BufferedInputStream bin = null;
        FileOutputStream fout = null;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            fout = new FileOutputStream(newfile);
            bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fout);
            bin = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

            log.info("Setting buffer to 1024");

            int total = 0;
            byte buf[] = new byte[1024]; // Buffer Size (works when set to 1)

            while((bin.read(buf)) != -1) {

                Float size = (float) newfile.length();

                bout.write(buf);
                total += buf.length;

                log.info("LOOP: Current Size:" + total + " New File Size: " + size + " Original Size: " + originalSize);
             }

            int size = (int) newfile.length();
            log.info("new file size bytes: " + size);
            log.info("original file size bytes: " + originalSize);
            log.info("File created: " + newfile.getName());

            return newfile.getName();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("ERROR: during input output file streaming: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            fis.close();
            bout.close();
            bin.close();
        }
```

So this works when I set the Buffer Size to 1 byte because it will completely write out the file

Any suggestions how I can get a buffered writer like this (I have to buffer it / use streams because it handles massive files) to write out the exact ammount of bytes for that file, It would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `Float size = (float) newfile.length();` ?????

Comment: Did you flush the out buffer?

Comment: You shouldn't talk about buffered stream writer when you mean buffered output stream. It's not the same.

Comment: You can replace all of this with a single call to [Files.copy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-).

Comment: @Andremoniy the size float above is just the size of the new file being created

Comment: @efekctive and no, how do I flush the out buffer. Ill look it up now

Comment: @VGR No the files are huge so I have to buffer them - we need up to 30gb-50 gb file uploads

Comment: What makes you think Files.copy is reading the entire file into memory before writing it to the destination?  I assure you it is not.

Comment: I would try bout.flush() before closing it. But give Files.* a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `read()` method returns the number of bytes read. The buffer isn't always fully filled.

You should write something like this:

```
int bytesRead = 0;
while((bytesRead = bin.read(buf)) != -1) {
  bout.write(buf, 0, bytesRead); // Write only the bytes read
  total += bytesRead;
  // ...
}
```